# Thread safe append to a file from Django application without Celery

Tags: django, python-2.7, thread-safety, append, locking

I have small Django application. During each request, I want to gather some request data (from custom middleware and some views) and append it to a file. Since the application is running in multithreaded environment, I want the append to be thread safe.

I have done some research, but most of the time people recommend celery. Since the application is very small, I would like to avoid using celery. I am ok with simple file locking, however, I do not know how to implement it with Django, where I do not manage the main thread directly.

The only thing I have found is [this](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/files/locks.py) Django's module, but it I am not sure if it solves my problem. Can I simply run that peace of code from my middleware?

```
from django.core.files import locks

with open('./file', 'wb') as f:
     locks.lock(f, locks.LOCK_EX)
     f.write('Django')
```

Comment: What version of python are you using? Meaning, is it possible for you to use [Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) and it's threadlocal storage for the file handle?

Comment: I am using python 2.7. Using queue is ok for me, if there is not any much simpler solution like the file lock for example.

Comment: Ack yeah, forgot it's in 2.7 as well.